# Django Form is not valid but not giving me an error

Tags: django, django-forms

In the below form If I uncomment "Product" field my form is not working.I think there is something wrong with my html file. I am not including whole model code only the neccessary code.

lead/models.py

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='lead_assigned_users')
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True)
    contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, related_name="lead_contacts")
    ctype = models.CharField(default=None,max_length=20, choices=TYPE, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.CharField(default=None,max_length=255, blank=False, null=True)
```

common/models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

lead/view.py

```
@login_required
def create_lead(request):
    template_name = "create_lead.html"

    if request.POST:
        form = LeadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, assigned_to=users)
        if form.is_valid():
            lead_obj = form.save(commit=False)
            lead_obj.created_by = request.user
            lead_obj.save()
            if request.POST.get('tags', ''):
                tags = request.POST.get("tags")
                splitted_tags = tags.split(",")
                for t in splitted_tags:
                    tag = Tags.objects.filter(name=t)
                    if tag:
                        tag = tag[0]
                    else:
                        tag = Tags.objects.create(name=t)
                    lead_obj.tags.add(tag)
            if request.POST.getlist('assigned_to', []):
                lead_obj.assigned_to.add(*request.POST.getlist('assigned_to'))
                assigned_to_list = request.POST.getlist('assigned_to')


            if request.POST.getlist('products', []):
                lead_obj.product.add(*request.POST.getlist('products'))
                products = request.POST.getlist('products')

            if request.POST.getlist('teams', []):
                user_ids = Teams.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('teams')).values_list('users', flat=True)
                assinged_to_users_ids = lead_obj.assigned_to.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
                for user_id in user_ids:
                    if user_id not in assinged_to_users_ids:
                        lead_obj.assigned_to.add(user_id)

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            recipients = list(lead_obj.assigned_to.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
            send_email_to_assigned_user.delay(recipients, lead_obj.id, domain=current_site.domain,
                protocol=request.scheme)

            if request.FILES.get('lead_attachment'):
                attachment = Attachments()
                attachment.created_by = request.user
                attachment.file_name = request.FILES.get(
                    'lead_attachment').name
                attachment.lead = lead_obj
                attachment.attachment = request.FILES.get('lead_attachment')
                attachment.save()

            if request.POST.get('status') == "converted":
                account_object = Account.objects.create(
                    created_by=request.user, name=lead_obj.account_name,
                    email=lead_obj.email, phone=lead_obj.phone,
                    description=request.POST.get('description'),
                    website=request.POST.get('website'),
                )
                account_object.billing_address_line = lead_obj.address_line
                account_object.billing_street = lead_obj.street
                account_object.billing_city = lead_obj.city
                account_object.billing_state = lead_obj.state
                account_object.billing_postcode = lead_obj.postcode
                account_object.billing_country = lead_obj.country
                for tag in lead_obj.tags.all():
                    account_object.tags.add(tag)

                if request.POST.getlist('assigned_to', []):
                    # account_object.assigned_to.add(*request.POST.getlist('assigned_to'))
                    assigned_to_list = request.POST.getlist('assigned_to')
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    recipients = assigned_to_list
                    send_email_to_assigned_user.delay(recipients, lead_obj.id, domain=current_site.domain,
                        protocol=request.scheme)

                account_object.save()
            success_url = reverse('leads:list')
            if request.POST.get("savenewform"):
                success_url = reverse("leads:add_lead")
            return JsonResponse({'error': False, 'success_url': success_url})
        return JsonResponse({'error': True, 'errors': form.errors})
    context = {}
    context["lead_form"] = form
    context["accounts"] = Account.objects.filter(status="open")
    context["users"] = users
    context["countries"] = COUNTRIES
    context["status"] = LEAD_STATUS
    context["source"] = LEAD_SOURCE
    context["ctype"] = TYPE
    context["product"] = Products.objects.all()
    context["assignedto_list"] = [int(i) for i in request.POST.getlist('assigned_to', []) if i]

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

create_lead.html

```
<form id="lead_form" method="POST" action="" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="overview_form_block row marl justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title text-center">
            {% if lead_obj %}EDIT{% else %}CREATE{% endif %} LEAD
          </div>
          <div class="row marl no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="filter_col col-md-6">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="name" >First Name{% if lead_form.first_name.field.required %}<span class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                      {{ lead_form.first_name }}
                      <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_first_name">{{ lead_form.first_name.errors }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filter_col col-md-6">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="name" >Last Name{% if lead_form.last_name.field.required %}<span class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                      {{ lead_form.last_name }}
                      <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_last_name">{{ lead_form.last_name.errors }}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1" {% if request.POST.status == "converted" %} class="required" {% endif %}>Account Name{% if lead_form.account_name.field.required %}<span class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                  {{ lead_form.account_name }}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_account_name">{{ lead_form.account_name.errors }}</span>
                  {% if error %}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_}">{{ error }}</span>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title{% if lead_form.title.field.required %}<span class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                  {{ lead_form.title }}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_title">{{ lead_form.title.errors }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group ">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Phone{% if lead_form.phone.field.required %}<span class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                  {{ lead_form.phone }}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_phone">{{ lead_form.phone.errors }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group ">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="required">Email Address{% if lead_form.email.field.required %}<span class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                  {{ lead_form.email }}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_email">{{ lead_form.email.errors }}</span>
                  {% if error %}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_}">{{ error }}</span>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Attachment</label>
                  <input type="file" name="lead_attachment" id="lead_attachment">
                  {% if lead_obj.lead_attachment.count %}
                    {% for attachment in lead_obj.lead_attachment.all %}
                    <div id="attachment{{attachment.id}}" class="mt-2">
                      <a target="_blank" href="{{ attachment.attachment.url }}">{{ attachment.file_name }}</a>
                      {% if not attachment.created_by.role == 'ADMIN' or attachment.created_by.role == request.user.role %}
                      <a class="action btn primary_btn"  onclick="remove_attachment({{attachment.id}})">X</a>
                      {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}
                  <span class="error"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Website{% if lead_form.website.field.required %}<span class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                  {{ lead_form.website }}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_website">{{ lead_form.website.errors }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1" >Description{% if lead_form.description.field.required %}<span class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                  {{ lead_form.description }}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_description">{{ lead_form.description.errors }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% if request.user.is_superuser or request.user.role == 'ADMIN' %}
              <div class="filter_col col-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="id_sattus">Teams{% if lead_form.teams.field.required %}<span
                      class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                  {{ lead_form.teams }}
                  <span class="error" id="id__teams">{{ lead_form.teams.errors }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% endif %}
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Assigned Users</label>
                  <select class="assigned_users form-control" name="assigned_to" multiple="multiple">
                  {% for user in users %}
                  <option value="{{user.id}}" {% if user in lead_obj.assigned_to.all or user.id in assignedto_list %} selected="" {% endif %}>{{user.email}}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_assigned_to">{{ lead_form.assigned_to.errors }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1"/>Status{% if lead_form.status.field.required %}<span class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                  {{ lead_form.status }}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_status">{{ lead_form.status.errors }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1"/>Source{% if lead_form.source.field.required %}<span class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                  {{ lead_form.source }}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_source">{{ lead_form.source.errors }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1" >Address</label>
                  {{ lead_form.address_line }}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_address_line">{{ lead_form.address_line.errors }}</span>
                </div>
                {{ lead_form.street }}
                <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_street">{{ lead_form.street.errors }}</span>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{ lead_form.city }}
                    <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_city">{{ lead_form.city.errors }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{ lead_form.state }}
                    <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_state">{{ lead_form.state.errors }}</span>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    {{ lead_form.postcode }}
                    <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_postcode">{{ lead_form.postcode.errors }}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:10px;">
                    {{ lead_form.country }}
                    <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_country">{{ lead_form.country.errors }}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div class="filter_col col-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Tags</label>
                  <div class="txt-box-div" id="tag-div"><input type="text" name="tags" id="tags_1" value="{% for t in lead_obj.tags.all %}{{t.name}}, {% endfor %}" class="tags"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1"/>Type{% if lead_form.ctype.field.required %}<span class="error">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                  {{ lead_form.ctype }}
                  <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_type">{{ lead_form.ctype.errors }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="filter_col col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Products</label>
                  <select class="assigned_users form-control" name="products" multiple="multiple">
                  {% for pro in product %}
                  <option value="{{user.id}}" {% if pro in lead_obj.product.all %} selected="" {% endif %}>{{pro.name}}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                 <span class="error error_message" id="error_id_products">{{ lead_form.product.errors }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="row marl buttons_row text-center form_btn_row">
                <button  class="btn btn-default save" type="submit" id="submit_btn">Save</button>
                {% if not lead_obj %}
                <button class="btn btn-success save savenew" type="submit">Save & New</button>
                {% endif %}
                <a href="{% url 'leads:list' %}" class="btn btn-default clear" id="create_lead_cancel">Cancel</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`enter code here`
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="save_new_form" name="savenewform">
  </div>
</form>
```

my ajax code

```
$('form#lead_form').ajaxForm({
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    url: ".",
    data:$('#lead_form').serialize(),
    beforeSubmit:  disableButton,
    beforeSend: function() {
      var percentVal = '0%';
      bar.width(percentVal);
      percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
      var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
      bar.width(percentVal);
      if (percentVal == '100%'){
        percent.html('Uploading ...')
      }
      else{
        percent.html(percentVal);
      }
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.error){
        $('#progress_bar').hide()
        $('.error_message').html('')
        for (var key in data.errors) {
          $('#error_id_'+key).html("<p>" + data.errors[key][0] + "</p>");
        };
        $('#submit_btn').removeAttr('disabled')
      }
      else{
        window.location = data.success_url;
      }
    }
  });
```

The form should be submitted successfully but, it's not working and not giving me an error.

Comment: You've posted a lot of irrelevant code here but don't seem to have actually shown the code for the form. And why do you have all those separate items that you're taking directly from request.POST?

Comment: What happens exactly when you submit the form? Why is your view returning a JsonResponse?

Comment: And why don't you set a breakpoint in the line of code `return JsonResponse(...)` to look at your `form.errors` in your debugger?

Comment: There are two questions: 1. you don't know why there's an error in your form, so I'm telling you to use your debugger to see the errors. 2. the errors aren't shown to the user, but since your view is returning a JsonResponse, it seems like the form is submitted using ajax. So to show the errors of the form to the user, you need to display them in the error handling javascript.

Comment: The problem with this question is that you're showing us a huge amount of code that we're supposed to debug (and missing the most relevant parts, the form and the ajax handling the response) when the easiest way to answer your question is use a debugger to actually look at the error.

Comment: I am getting Nonetype object has no attribute add on line  lead_obj.product.add(*request.POST.getlist('products')) but I can see data if I print out request.POST

Comment: I am also getting error <ul class="errorlist"><li>product<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul> but this field is not required and also there is multiple values in that field